# correct usage doSNOW or doParallel for a simple repetitive task

Tags: r, doparallel

I have a simple task: my input is a list of URL's, my function is an extraction of nodes and saving as csv.

```
myfun = function(url){
output = read_html(url) %>%
            html_nodes("a") %>%
            html_attr("href")
    write.csv(output , paste0("output/",output,".csv"))
}
```

I need to run this function for hundreds of URL's and it is very slow in a loop.

So what I tried is the following:

```
library(doParallel)  

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1  
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)  
# cl = 12
registerDoParallel(cl)  

start_time <- Sys.time()
result <- foreach(i=list_urls, .packages=c("dplyr",'rvest','httr','stringr')) %dopar%  
  myfun(i)

end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time-start_time)

stopCluster(cl)
```

First of all: my computer has 4 cores but somehow when I input 12 it runs faster.
Second: this does increase the whole process, instead of 4 hours it now takes 20 minutes.

I was wondering if this is the best I can do?
Are there any alternatives to makes this even faster?

The `read_html` is a function which takes a while for some links and I cannot do anything about so the idea is to run it on multiple cores/threads or whatever the correct wording is.

Thank you

Comment: Have you benchmarked `myfun`? I'm guessing `read_html` is your bottleneck? Depending on the URLs you might want to be careful here. You could easily create something that looks like a DOS attack.

Comment: or is against TOS.

Comment: Yes that is the bottleneck. My url's are very custom and I don't run this function more often that once a day.

Comment: Then this is probably the best you can do. Only other option would be to throw more cores at this but see comments above.